# Owl-carousel на нужном разрешении

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Использую `owl-carousel` в двух секциях. В первой секции слайдер идёт на всех разрешениях. А во второй секции слайдер должен включаться только на разрешениях меньше `700px`. Как это можно реализовать?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    items: 1,
    nav: true,
    navText: "",
  });
});

<div class="review">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-carousel1">
            <div class="owl-carusel__item">
                <p>Это приложение перевернуло мой мир и позволило по-новому взглянуть на привычные серые вещи! А еще я познакомился со своей будущей женой в комментариях к выложенной фотографии!</p>
                <span class="owl-carusel__item-name">Николай Петров</span>
                <span class="owl-carusel__item-descr">25 лет, водитель трамвая</span>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-carusel__item">
                <p>Это приложение перевернуло мой мир и позволило по-новому взглянуть на привычные серые вещи! А еще я познакомился со своей будущей женой в комментариях к выложенной фотографии!</p>
                <span class="owl-carusel__item-name">Тимур Бойко</span>
                <span class="owl-carusel__item-descr">43 лет, адвокат</span>
            </div>
            <div class="owl-carusel__item">
                <p>Это приложение перевернуло мой мир и позволило по-новому взглянуть на привычные серые вещи! А еще я познакомился со своей будущей женой в комментариях к выложенной фотографии!</p>
                <span class="owl-carusel__item-name">Максим Морозов</span>
                <span class="owl-carusel__item-descr">21 лет, электрик</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>





<div class="prices">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="owl-carousel" id="owl-carousel2">
            <div class="prices-container">
                <table class="prices-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>база<span>1,99 usd</span></th>
                        <th>стандарт<span>3,99 usd</span><span class="prices-table__baner">хит</span></th>
                        <th>анлим<span>9,99 usd</span></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Розовый фильтр</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Смайлики</td>
                        <td class="no"></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Комментарии</td>
                        <td class="no"></td>
                        <td class="no"></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сделайте сниппет.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай проверку на разрешение экрана

```
if ($(window).width() < 700) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            items: 1,
            nav: true,
            navText: "",
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но стоит немного другая задача. Во-первых такая проверка скрывает и первую карусель тоже. А на этом разрешении нужно подлючать только вторую. Во-вторых подобная проверка полностью убирает блок карусели на страничке. А нужно чтобы контент оставался всегда, включалась только карусель.

Comment: @FghsdfsdfFghfghfdsf вместо селектора `.owl-carousel` используйте id элементов. Для двух эл-тов нужно вызывать `owlCarousel()` отдельно. HTML разметку приведите, я не знаю, как у вас контент отображается.

Comment: Вызывать карусель отдельно, дейстительно отличная идея, спасибо. Теперь осталось понять, как подключить именно карусель на маленьком разрешении, при том, чтобы контент оставался всегда :) HTML код добавил к первому сообщению. Спасибо Вам за помощь )

Comment: @FghsdfsdfFghfghfdsf в вашей разметке только один элемент с классом `owl-carousel`

Comment: Я скинул только вторую секцию, сейчас добавлю и первую, извините.

Comment: @FghsdfsdfFghfghfdsf Чтобы контент не скрывался можете удалить не использовать класс `owl-carousel`.